Prove or disprove that $|(1/\zeta)^{(n)}(x)| \leq \frac{n!}{(x-\frac{1}{2})}$ for all real $x>1$
$|(1/\zeta)^{(n)}(x)| \leq \frac{n!}{(x-\frac{1}{2})}$ for all real $x>1$.
I had this conjecture for a long time. I tried various methods and techniques but they all failed. It might also be wrong since my last conjecture turned out to be wrong. But the data suggests that it might be true since two weak versions n=1,n=2. I tried to generalize the methods proposed in the answers. I tried to prove it by induction by using Leibniz rule but everything got complicated so I decided to share the conjecture in case anyone has enough knowledge to prove/disprove it. Anyway ,here are some plots:

